# RegEx formula - ignoring quotation

Tags: regex

I want to find RegEx formula which will return me back everything besides quotations from last message. I don't want to have full conversation, but only one message.

```
Hi my little friend,


Kind regards,
Name Surname
text
<link>
<web>
some numbers
01 02 03 04 05
 <https://www.facebook.com/balr>     <https://twitter.com/balr>    <http://instagram.com/balr>     <http://bybalr.tumblr.com/

>date, at 15:00, someone wrote:
>some quoting 
>more quotes
>and text
><http://google.com/>.
>nanana
>blablabla
```

will return back only this:

```
Hi my little friend,


Kind regards,
Name Surname
text
<link>
<web>
some numbers
01 02 03 04 05
 <https://www.facebook.com/balr>     <https://twitter.com/balr>    <http://instagram.com/balr>     <http://bybalr.tumblr.com/
```

I tried to do it with:

```
(^([^>])).*$
```

but it returns too much, because it returns:

```
Name Surname
text
<link>
<web>
some numbers
01 02 03 04 05
 <https://www.facebook.com/balr>     <https://twitter.com/balr>    <http://instagram.com/balr>     <http://bybalr.tumblr.com/

>date, at 15:00, someone wrote:
```

Without last line it would be ok. Any ideas?

Comment: Using a lookahead: `^(?!>).*$`

Comment: `/^[\s\S]*?(?=\s>)/`

Comment: @Sebastian Proske Does not work it. Returns only 2 first lines.

Comment: Working fine for me: https://regex101.com/r/6IptVZ/1 What tool/language are you using?

Comment: I use this: http://regexr.com/.

Comment: It does not resolve my problems, but it seems they are somewhere else. Thank you for help.

Comment: Where do you plan to use this?